# Remove directory from url htaccess apache

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website where all the files were in the public_html root so my urls were `http://foo.com/index.php`

I have moved all my files into a bar directory so now the url is: `http://foo.com/bar/index.php` however I would like to rewrite the URLs so that the the directory bar is not shown in the urls and the site still appears as `http://foo.com/index.php`. What is the best way of achieving this? I have LAMP hosting and can change htaccess files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your .htaccess under public_html:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!bar/).*)$ bar/$1 [NC,L]
```

Then you can access your website as `http://foo.com/index.php`