# How to Remove main category from URL in K2 in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

What I have: Joomla 2.58 , K2 , sh404sef

Problem : I want to put K2 main category on my Homepage, so it shows a few folders of Sub-categories... But I don't want the main category to be seen in URL. But all other categories should be seen.
How to do that?!

- For example, now, after sh404sef I'm getting url :
  http://mypage.com/all-categories/clothes/
- But I want it to be:
  http://mypage.com/clothes/   //Because Main-Category have nothing, only Sub's..

Comment: Might be a situation for .htaccess and URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to select all the sub-categories for the menu item instead of the parent?

OR

[Remove directory from url htaccess apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516852/remove-directory-from-url-htaccess-apache)

In .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!all-categories/).*)$ bar/$1 [NC,L]
```