# Symfony2 project in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I'm currently working on a Symfony2 application that, for the time being, has to be hosted inside a subdirectory. Normally one would change the DocumentRoot in the Apache vhost but this is currently not possible. It's also not possible to place anything in the root directory (e.g. above `public_html/`).

The DocumentRoot is set at `/public_html/`. The structure with the Symfony2 app in a subdirectory looks like this:

```
- public_html/
-- dev/
---- app/
---- bin/
---- src/
---- vendor/
---- web/
```

Without any special configuration the app can be reached at http://example.com/dev/web/app.php. I however want to change this to http://example.com/dev without having to move files around.

I came up with the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dev/web/
RewriteRule (.*) /dev/web/app.php/$1 [L]
```

This kinda works, but Symfony2 reports the following error: `No route found for "GET /dev/"`.

If I change the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule (.*) /dev/web/$1 [L]` I can reach the app with http://example.com/dev/app.php/dashboard (dashboard being an example of course) which results in `No route found for "GET hboard"`, notice **hboard**. Calling http://example.com/dev/app.php/ does render the page at / perfectly and links to all assets work fine as well.

Any help would be much appreciated. In time this app has to move from `dev/` to `/` as well. So a solution for that is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

The default `web/.htaccess` file from *Symfony2* looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You should add `dev/web/` before `app.php` and move it to your root directory.

#### EDIT:

After some research I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9521241/1847340). So the new `.htaccess` should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?!dev/web/).*)$ dev/web/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also look at

- [Symfony: htaccess to hide app.php or app_dev.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689822/symfony-htaccess-to-hide-app-php-or-app-dev-php)
- [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php)

Comment: As stated in the question I can't change the DocumentRoot.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. Updated my answer. I hope this is more helpful.

Comment: This still results in the error `No route found for "GET /dev/dashboard"` or `"GET /dev/"` for `/`.

Comment: Updated Answer again.

Comment: Is it the root directory e.g. public_html or public_html/dev where I need to put the .htaccess? I've already tried the latter but that didn't give the desired results. Looking at the paths I guess it should be in public_html?

Comment: I decided to move everything up into the root directory. All I've got to do now is that stuff from the bundles/ directory will be server, but that's just a simple rewrite away.